# Download files from connected FTP with Node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, ftp

I'm rushing to find a solution for my problem!

At the moment I'm connected to an FTP and I selected 5 files to download, but I can't get the correct diretory for both local and remote path.

On the remote ftp, I am inside a folder named OUT and this folder contains 5 files that I want to download.

On local, I want to download to my project folder > files.

Here is my code:

```
ftps.cd('./OUT')
.raw('ls')
.exec(function(err, res){
    var arr = [];

    var items = res.data.split('\n')//.map(String);
    var item;
    //console.log(items);

    for (i in items){

        item = items[i];
        if(item.length > 0 ){


            var linha = item.toString().slice(46);

            var date = linha.toString().substr(0,12);
            var date_timestamp = moment([2018, months[date.substr(0,3)], date.substr(7,2), date.substr(5,2), date.substr(10,2)]).format('x');

            var nome_ficheiro = linha.toString().slice(13);
            // console.log(nome_ficheiro)

            // split files
            //-rwxrwxrwx   1 owner    group           79563 Jul 17 10:44 STKHYN_20180713170017.csv

            var fl = [];
            // fl['datea'] = moment([2018, months[date.substr(0,3)], date.substr(7,2), date.substr(5,2), date.substr(10,2)]);
                fl['date'] = date_timestamp;
                fl['filename'] = nome_ficheiro;

            arr.push(fl);
        }
    }

    // filter array
    arr = _.sortBy(arr, "date").reverse();

    // first 5 files
    arr = arr.splice(0,5);

    // get files
    for (i in arr){
        ftps.put("files/text.txt", "/");
        ftps.get(arr[i]['filename']);
    }
    console.log(arr); 
    });
```

Could you guys please help me?

Comment: have you tried using absolute path? I dont think that when ftp connects it will redirect you to the default path, like usual.

Comment: @Chris initially I put the cd on the folder " OUT/ ", but the ftp that I'm connected have two folders "IN" and "OUT", when I enter the folder "OUT", I should be able to put the files I want, inside this folder on my computer "c:/xampp/htdocs/test_folder/files/".. But I can't get the correct dir name.. how should I do that?